# Using linear referencing for real time traffic in ArcGIS Network Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, network-analyst, traffic

I'm using real time customized traffic for Network Analysis in ArcGIS 10.2.2.

The traffic display as segment based. In other words, when i want to show free flow for a road i have to assign one or more segment(s) as free flow.  But i want to assign a part of a segment as free flow not entire segment.

Is it possible to assign traffic as part of a segment?

Comment: I guess when you say segment you mean a polyline? Once your network is converted to a PolylineM featureclass and has measure assigned to it (referered to as calibration) you can certainly create linear segments that are shorter than the polyline. You just need to turn your XY data into measure distances along the route.

Comment: @Hornbydd but traffic service works with only xy data.

Comment: You would use [this](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Locate_Features_Along_Routes/003m00000007000000/) tool to locate XY data to a route.